# Combining minted and a colorbox into one command

Tags: xetex, minted

I have a minted configuration:

```
\renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{\small\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}

\newminted{cpp}{
    linenos=true,
    xleftmargin=2em,
    breaklines,
    fontsize=\small,
}
```

And a tcolorbox configuration:

```
\newtcolorbox{box-note}{
    sharpish corners, % better drop shadow
    boxrule = 0pt,
    toprule = 4.5pt, % top rule weight
    enhanced,
    drop fuzzy shadow = black!35,
    fontupper=\sffamily
}
```

Using these together means that I have to write:

```
\begin{box-note}
\begin{cppcode}
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
\end{cppcode}
\end{box-note}
```

This works and looks great, but it's annoying that I have to always repeat these two environments. Is there a way to put these two together?

I tried `\newenvironment` but minted seems to explode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tcolorbox` have build-in `minted` support. You can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,minted}
\renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{\small\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}

\newtcblisting{boxcppnote}{
    sharpish corners, % better drop shadow
    boxrule = 0pt,
    toprule = 4.5pt, % top rule weight
    enhanced,
    drop fuzzy shadow = black!35,
    fontupper=\sffamily,
    listing only,
    minted language=cpp,
    minted options={
    linenos=true,
    xleftmargin=2em,
    breaklines,
    fontsize=\small,}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{boxcppnote}
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
\end{boxcppnote}
\end{document}
```

[image]